# ¿Cómo hago para generar un archivo plano del resultado de una consulta?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy generando un proceso almacenado que me permita mostrar ciertos datos, cosa que ya he completado pero debo pasar los resultados de dicha consulta a un archivo plano. Cabe resaltar el hecho de que soy un completo novicio en temas de `sql server` y estoy atento ante cualquier respuesta.

tengo una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
select es.estud_nombre1,estud_ape2,es.estud_documento,gr.grup_nom,ps.materias,hr.hora_inicio,hr.hora_fin
 from estudiantes es
 inner join grupos gr
 on gr.id = es.grupos_id
 inner join pensum ps
 on gr.id = ps.grupos_id
 inner join horarios hr
 on hr.id = ps.horarios_id
 where gr.grup_nom='grupo 3'
 order by es.estud_nombre1
```

Lo que necesito es pasar el resultado de esta consulta a un archivo plano ('CSV')

Comment: @Aprendiz bueno, siendo honesto la duda está escrita en el título de la pregunta. Podemos hablar de cómo faltarían detalles en el cuerpo del post, pero la pregunta parece clara

Comment: @Aprendiz yo no soy el usuario que hizo la pregunta, simplemente estoy respondiendo a tu comentario inicial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo quieres realizar directamente desde SQL Server sin necesidad de una utilería, lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

Realiza tu consulta y mediante el menú contextual selecciona la opción "Save Results as..."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y seleccionar el tipo como .CSV :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

También puedes instalar  y utilizar la [utileria **BCP**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) para poder guardar la consulta en un archivo .CSV.

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM MyTable" queryout "C:\MyTable.csv" -c -t , -S SERVERNAME -T
```

Revisa:

[SQL Server, escribir el resultado seleccionado en un archivo .csv (inglés)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: ¿Usas Windows 7? :O

Comment: Hahaha @Phi si, me ví muy "old fashioned"???

Comment: LOL! No te preocupes, lo de hoy es lo "retro"

Comment: @Elenasys de tu manera lo logré hacer ya que debido a que la consola está restringida no pude usar bcp, gracias a todos por resolver mi duda :)

Comment: Excelente @johnbarrera, un placer ayudarte, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo y rápido de como generar un archivo de texto a partir de una consulta:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 
'bcp "SELECT * FROM Personas" queryout "C:\test_data_personas.txt" -T -c -t,'
```

espero que te ayude.